# FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException:The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO ]

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, kotlin

In facebook login callback return success but firebase auth.signInWithCredential is return task is not successfull with exception; FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException:The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Remote site 5XX from facebook.com for USER_INFO ]

My facebook developer app type is Gaming services. When i looking on the web for solution, some say change apptype is work but imposibble due to app is live. Any suggestion?

```
binding.btnFacebookMan.registerCallback(callbackManager,object :
            FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
            override fun onCancel() {
                Log.d("log","facebook login cancelled")
            }

            override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                Log.d("log","facebook ${error.message}")
            }

            override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
               val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(result.accessToken.token)
                    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(act) {task->
                        if(task.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d("log","taskSuccess")
                            val mail = task.result.user?.email
                            val uid = task.result.user?.uid
                        } else {
                            Log.d("log","taskFail")
                            Log.d("log","${task.exception}")
                            loader.dismiss()
                        }
                    }     
            }
        })
```